# Как настроить localhost в Linux (PHP + MySQL или PostgreSQL)?

Tags: apache, opensuse, localhost, linux

Проблема такая: не захотел я ставить XAMPP и поставил по отдельности (Apache, MySQL, PostgreSQL) - теперь не знаю, как настроить все это! Вначале заработало "It works!" теперь и это не работает, пробовал закинуть phpinfo.php в папку `/serv/www/htdocs/`, но пишет

> `Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected. Error 403`

Как мне все это настроить, что бы заработало? Система openSuse 11.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что к папке нет доступа для текущего пользователя. Надо выставить нужные права. Для пробы дать всем все права

```
chmod -R 777 /serv/www/htdocs/
```

И для проверки можно добавить в папку файл test.php с содержимым `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` и посмотреть его по адресу `/serv/www/htdocs/test.php`.

А обычно шаги по установке такие.

Установить веб-сервер

```
yast2 –install apache2
```

Установить PHP5

```
yast2 –install php5 php5-mysql apache2-mod_php5
```

Установить MySQL

```
yast2 –install mysql mysql-tools
```

Запустить веб-сервер

```
rcapache2 start
```

Запустить сервер базы данных

```
rcmysql start
```

Задать пароль базы данных

```
mysqladmin -u root -p pass
```

Установить phpMyAdmin

```
yast2 –install phpMyAdmin
```

Скопировать настройки по умолчанию

```
cd /srv/www/htdocs/phpMyAdmincp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

Прописать секретный ключ

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ‘something’;
```

Теперь на странице http://localhost/phpMyAdmin настройки, а на странице http://localhost - пробный сайт.

Почитать по теме можно здесь: [Настройка HTTP Сервера (Apache)](http://ru.opensuse.org/SDB:%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_HTTP_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(Apache)#.D0.A1.D0.B0.D0.BC.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.BA_HTTP_.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0).

Comment: поставил права - apache заработал,но php не хочет! скорее всего из-за того,что я снес версию 5.3 и поставил 5.2,теперь не знаю,что и как прописать!заодно сейчас поставил XAMPP 1.7. со старой версией php тоже  не запускается php файл